# why is the local field Q_l not an etale sheaf over a scheme X? 

Tags: etale-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I would like to know the reason why the local field Q_l is not an etale sheaf over a scheme X while its ring of integers Z_l can be regarded as a constant etale sheaf?

Comment: I sort of answered this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83569/why-is-the-definition-of-l-adic-sheaves-so-complicated/83573#83573

Comment: I don't understand.  You can make an étale sheaf out of any group.